# Working with Gerber Artwork Definition Files

Tags: design, gerber

I am currently in the process of re-working an internal program for a company. This program takes general templates for various signs that are customized with specific lines of text and then printed to vinyl. The program has almost no comments in the source code and outputs files with the extension .GAD
I have managed to figure out this is a type of Gerber file but when I look at the plain text for the file it looks wildly different from what the official Gerber file specification looks like. Has anyone had experience with these types of files or know of the specification for this type of file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about software used for producing signs rather than electronics.

Answer (score 1):

[Internet](http://extension.informer.com/gad/) shows the following:

> Gerber OMEGA design and output software is a complete suite of layout, design, output and conversion tools created specifically for use in the sign industry. OMEGA design and output tools are fine-tuned to accommodate vinyl cutting, printing and routing on sign industry production devices such as Gerber **vinyl cutters**, the Gerber EDGE® family of **thermal printers**, as well as Gerber routers and flatbed cutters.

To my understanding Gerber manufactures different devices, thus having different file formats supported. Your file format does not have relation to PCB manufacturing. Here's the [link](http://www.gspinc.com/products/software/omega) to Gerber OMEGA software, probably you will find file format definition there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have gotten to this point in my research as well. I can find ample information regarding the printer hardware the company is using (Gerber EDGE 2) and the RS-274X / RS-274-D file specifications but have not found a single mention across hundreds of pages of documentation regarding the GAD file format. Again, thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Why not ask manufacturer? Send them email. It seems file format spec is not widely available. As @ScottSeidman proposed - why not you ask people around for information?

Comment: https://www.ucamco.com/files/downloads/file/81/the_gerber_file_format_specification.pdf

Comment: The printer recommends GAPlot32.  A search for the Gerber language reference with that program yielded the above.  Of course, optimizing such output might be a big computational problem.

Answer (score 0):

How in the world are you supposed to rework an internal program if you have no idea of what the program does?  This is a program for disaster.

If nobody there can tell you what the GAD files are for, you don't need to make them because nobody is using them.

If you're just asking people external to the company because you don't want to ask anyone inside the company, you need to rethink this.  There's nothing embarrassing about telling people who expect a successful job that you need more information.  It's embarrassing to get it wrong because you didn't ask.

Comment: Scott, in some cultures it is unacceptable to show that you have difficulties performing the task assigned, and this discussion is for Workplace section of the SE.

Comment: @Anonymous I've worked with people for such cultures over the year, but still can't dredge up sympathy in this case.  If you don't know what the program is for, you don't even have a situation where you can test the solution.  "I'm having trouble" is not the same as "I need you to share information with me".  At the very least, the OP can ask "what equipment will be using the generated files?" which would clarify everything once the OP did the footwork.

Comment: The program makes files to be printed on a EDGE 2 printer- I understand that they are taking a generic template of text and visual items to be placed within the file and this process is done in vector format. As I am currently perceiving you are more upset about the reworking an application part of the issue versus the main point of asking if anyone had worked with this file format before I would ask that you please narrow the focus of your answer to pertain to the file format in question and not my workplace practices.